# DDEBUG=0 doesn't work

Tags: c, debugging, gcc, c-preprocessor

I'm learning the gcc option `DDEBUG`.
Below is my simple code for testing:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


#ifdef DEBUG
    #define debug(msg) printf("Debug: %s\n", msg)
#else
    #define debug(msg)
#endif

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{

    debug("Debug flag was defined\n");

    printf("hello world\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Then, I compiled with `gcc -DDEBUG=0 debug.c`, I expect "Debug flag was defined" will not be printed, however it does. May I know why `-DDEBUG=0` does not work?

Comment: Maybe you are confusing `#ifdef` with `#if`

Answer (score 3):

The preprocessor conditions doesn't work like that. When you define `DEBUG` to be equal to some value (doesn't matter which), it is still *defined* which means `#ifdef` will be "true".

Either do not define the macro at all (which is the "normal" way), or use `#if` like

```
#if DEBUG != 0
    #define debug(msg) printf("Debug: %s\n", msg)
#else
    #define debug(msg)
#endif
```